# Is it safe to edit user based on devise current_user helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Devise, Omniauth-twitter and Omniauth-facebook for my rails app authentication and i had to make my own controller for editing user parameters without needing a password for users with providers like facebook and twitter.
And instead of routing the user to his profile by his user id, I used the devise helper current_user to show and edit the current_user parameters 
My question is.. is it safe to do that ?
I'm a beginner.. so when something is done that easy i worry about security vulnerabilities. Here's my code.

profile_controller.rb

```
class ProfileController < ApplicationController
   before_action :authenticate_user!
   def show
       @user = current_user
   end

   def edit
       @profile = current_user
   end
   def update 
       @profile = current_user
       if @profile.update(profile_params)
           redirect_to profile_path(@profile)
       else
           render 'edit'
       end
   end
   private
   def profile_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:username,:first_name,:last_name,:gender)
   end
end
```

routes.rb

```
get'profile' => 'profile#show'
get'profile/edit' => 'profile#edit'
patch'profile/edit' => 'profile#update'
```

edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @profile, url: {action: "edit"} do |f| %>

    <%= f.text_field :username, autofocus: true %>

    <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true %>

    <%= f.text_field :last_name, autofocus: true %>

    <%= f.text_field :gender, autofocus: true %>

    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are using Devise you could make user of their existing views rather than, you trying to implement them on your own. But, I don't see any security threats with your current approach it's just that it is a waste of time.

Take a look at the devise documentation and check the **Configuring Views** section,

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise